# Enable autocompletion feature for kivy .kv file in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, kivy

I finally succeeded in configuring kivy on Eclipse but I still can't find out if I can enable autocompletion feature for .kv file? Any ideas, how to?

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm can provide the autocomplete needed: Follow the instructions on this link:

[How to configure Python Kivy for PyCharm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016259/how-to-configure-python-kivy-for-pycharm-on-windows)

It is a little bit confusing, but you can do it.