# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. Kivy (Python 2.7) for Pyscripter on Windows 64x

Tags: python-2.7, 64-bit, importerror, kivy, pyscripter

I am running on an 64x machine with python 2.7 and Kivy and I set it up for pyscripter.

So I used the script from the second answer to this stackoverflow question

[Can I run a Kivy program from within Pyscripter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625312/can-i-run-a-kivy-program-from-within-pyscripter)

Basically I went in to Tools and 'Edit Startup Script' and replace `kivy_path` on the script to where my kivy directory.

```
# This startup script makes it possible to Pyscripter to work with the kivy package

import sys
import os

kivy_path = 'C:/kivy27'
relative_modules_paths = ['/kivy',
                          '/Python/',
                          '/Python/Lib/',
                          '/Python/Lib/Site-packages/',]

# tells the interpreter to look for python modules in the kivy modules' paths
for relative_path in relative_modules_paths:
    sys.path.append( kivy_path+relative_path )

# sets some environment variables needed by kivy. Not permanent.
os.environ['GST_PLUGIN_PATH'] = kivy_path+'/gstreamer/lib/gstreamer-0.10'
os.environ['GST_REGISTRY'] = kivy_path+'gstreamer/registry.bin'

kivy_environ_paths = '{kp};{kp}/Python;{kp}/gstreamer/bin;{kp}/MinGW/bin;'
kivy_environ_paths = kivy_environ_paths.format( kp=kivy_path )

os.environ['PATH'] = kivy_environ_paths

# theorecally your environment variables won't be affected outside the
# interpreter. You can still backup your environment variables if you
# don't feel confident
```

Writing the code functions fine for python so far. (I have not used kivy language yet)

When I try to run the code I get

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\python\main.py   12      
    <module>    C:/kivy27/kivy\kivy\app.py  321     
    <module>    C:/kivy27/kivy\kivy\base.py 29      
    <module>    C:/kivy27/kivy\kivy\event.py    8       
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

But if I put it into the BAT file it runs fine. So I am guessing there is something wrong with the Pyscripter setup code.

Here is the code I am running:

```
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        l = Label(text='Hello',
                  font_size=150)
        f.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(l)
        return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

It is basically from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7UKmK9eQLY

Comment: Can you post the exact path you added to pyscripter?