# How to get syntax highlighting on Kivy, .kv, file in Pycharm on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, kivy-language

What are the steps needed to get syntax highlighting on `.kv` files in PyCharm on OSX?

Comment: To be honest, even though this question was already asked, the answer here is far more easy to understand and implement as compared to the older question.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The import settings for PyCharm can be found here:
https://github.com/Zen-CODE/kivybits/tree/master/IDE

> **KV Lang File Type Support**
>
> - Download [this file](https://github.com/Zen-CODE/kivybits/blob/master/IDE/PyCharm_kv_completion.jar?raw=true)
> - On Pycharm’s main menu, click "File"-> "Import" (or Import Settings)
> - Select this file and PyCharm will present a dialog with filetypes    ticked. Click OK.
> - You are done. Restart PyCharm.

Comment: One more addition here. After adding cloud synchronization of settings we need to disable it first before import settings. Otherwise, no `Import Settings` option will appear. This setting at `File -> IDE Settings Sync -> Disable Sync..`

Comment: This answer is pretty old and Pycharm changed the settings path. Now you find it under: `File -> Manage IDE settings -> Import Settings...`

Comment: I did this, and it works however now in the pycharm git bash terminal whenever I try to run `source` on an "activate" file to activate a virtual environment it returns `bash: basename: command not found` . Some other commands don't work after doing this either like `ls` but then some still do work like `cd`. Explanation?