# .kv file issue with pycharm

Tags: pycharm, kivy

I am working on pycharm trying to learn kivy. I am stuck with one thing that is how to open .kv file.
Every time I create a .kv file and then try to open the file it shows me an error of "How do you want to open this file?" It is a comman error that Windows shows if it does not have the right software to open the file.

[image]

I have pasted the screen shot above please help me with this. I have completely downloaded the entire kivy package.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this answer [How to configure Python Kivy for PyCharm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016259). And this answer [How to get syntax highlighting on Kivy, .kv, file in Pycharm on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38002630).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Python Kivy for PyCharm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016259/how-to-configure-python-kivy-for-pycharm-on-windows)

Comment: [This JetBrains post is also useful](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006289280-Unable-to-get-Kivy-to-work-with-Pycharm-Community-edition)